# & as &amp; in XML not working for google search console

Tags: xml, escaping, character

I did read many articles including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) one but still can't make it to work.
I have an xml with a link shown like this:

```
<loc>https://afremov.com/en/?target=product&amp;product_id=8460</loc>
```

but sitll getting an error from google and this from validator.w3.org:

> If you meant to include an entity that starts with "&", then you should terminate it with ";". Another reason for this error message is that you inadvertently created an entity by failing to escape an "&" character just before this text.

so it clearly doesn't see my escaped character. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: What's the XML declaration if any?

Comment: it's <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: May the error is somewhere else in the doc. Does validator.w3.org includes a line number for the error? Did you tried editing the xml with a good xml editor? Does the XML includes a namespace declaration (should no be the reason anyway)?

Comment: Just tested this fragment and passed validation `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<loc>https://afremov.com/en/?target=product&amp;product_id=8460</loc>`

Comment: Well it shows couple of errors before actual '&' issue:
Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document.
No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.

Then it's just one huge line
Line 3, Column 456452: cannot generate system identifier for general entity "product_id"

Comment: here is a full file, i've removed that glitchi entry already: https://afremov.com/?target=sitemap&index=2

Comment: You can accept the answer if you agree.

Comment: Luis, doesn't look like an answer and main idea is that when I fix that link it works perfectly